# Change the window title of a projector (both .app and .exe) file?

Tags: flash, projector

Is there a way to change the title of a projector file (I have both .app and .exe) without using a tool like Zinc?

Also, if I do have to use a tool to accomplish this, which tool works for both MAC/Windows (without having to buy a version for each platform??

By title, I mean the title that shows up in the projector window at the top...